# How would I get data from the text file and store it to a structure using vb?

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, file-io, data-structures

net with .net version 4.5 i have created a rich text file with the text

> > [username]lewis[password]foo[level]1[username]bob[password]hi[level]3

all on one line. I have a structure

## Structure

```
Public Structure User
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim Level As String
End Structure
```

I also have an array of this structure called **users**
How would I load the text file into the users structure.
I've tried using RegEx but it didn't go well so how would i split the text properly.

Comment: Said you attempted regex, what about matching groups like 
(\[username\])(?<UserName>\w+)(\[password\])(?<Password>\w+)(\[level\])(?<Level>\w+)

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always of that format you could do something like the following

```
Dim line As String = GetNextLine() 
Dim array = line.Split(new Char() { "["c, "]"c }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim user As new User()
user.username = array(1)
user.password = array(3)
user.level = array(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim line As String = "[username]lewis[password]foo[level]1[username]bob[password]hi[level]3"
    Dim parts1() As String = line.Split({"["c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each part1 As String In parts1
        Dim parts2() As String = part1.Split("]"c)
        Dim key As String = parts2(0)
        Dim value As String = parts2(1)
        Debug.WriteLine(key & " = " & value)
    Next
```

`Key` will be the string inside the square brackets, and `Value` will be the string that follows it.  You can do a `case / select` off of key to put the value in to the correct member of your structure.  This will easily let you add more fields or change their order.

Keep in mind that this will fail if the username or password contains square brackets.  If you want to allow those you will have to specially encode them.

Comment: if i have a users array how would i do say users(index).password = password